# numpy : assembling multiple slices into new array

Tags: python, numpy, slice

I have a 2-dimentional array, of which I need to extract sections (slices) into a new array:

```
original= numpy.ndarray( shape=(4,4) )
slices= numpy.ndarray( shape=(0,2) )
for x in range(3):
    slice= original[x:x+2,x:x+2] 
    slices=numpy.append(slices, slice,axis=0)
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this (getting rid of the python for cycle)?

**----EDIT----**

To clarify, I'm asking how to copy arbitrarily (but similarly) shaped 2D slices from arbitrary 2D indexes of an 2D array into another, vertically stacked - not particularly along the diagonal, or 2x2 sized.

Comment: Does the slice have to be square?

Comment: @Bitwise "arbitrarily (but similarly) shaped 2D slices", so, not necessarily square

Answer (score 3):

There is a nifty trick with `stride_tricks`, you can find rolling window functions with different generality on SO and other (there currently is none in numpy itself), here is a version tailored to what you got:

```
def rolling_window(arr, window):
    """Very basic multi dimensional rolling window. window should be the shape of
    of the desired subarrays. Window is either a scalar or a tuple of same size
    as `arr.shape`.
    """
    shape = np.array(arr.shape*2)
    strides = np.array(arr.strides*2)
    window = np.asarray(window)
    shape[arr.ndim:] = window # new dimensions size
    shape[:arr.ndim] -= window - 1
    if np.any(shape < 1):
        raise ValueError('window size is too large')
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(arr, shape=shape, strides=strides)

# Now:
view = rolling_window(arr, 2)
view[0,0] # first slice in your loop
```

Note that `view` holds the same data as the original array! Which can result in unexpected results. But you seem to want only the diagonal, you could do that with stride tricks as well to make sure you do not copy data if you want (next versions will create a view with `diagonal`, old ones always a copy):

```
diagonal = np.diagonal(view, axis1=0, axis2=1)
# unfortunatly now the first slice is diagonal[...,0], so just roll it to the start:
diagonal = np.rollaxis(diagonal, -1)
```

Now `diagonal` is the array you created in your for loop (on newer versions add a `.copy()` if you do not want a view).

Edit: Since the `slices` array is 2D and not 3D because you append, a reshape was missing here:

```
slices = diagonal.reshape(-1,2)
```

This might not be faster if you have such small arrays, but its constant (expect for the copying of the data in `diagonal` call) with the array size.

Comment: This simplifies the indexing, but how would one use it to achieve the final array ("slices" in the question) without using a for with numpy.append?

Comment: @goncalopp sorry I missed that while appending you are removing one dimension. This is only a reshape away though. Added it, though its a bit annoying maybe. I am not sure what you exactly want, but view can help you to get to the slices, from there it depends I guess...

Comment: nice! is there a way to generalize this to arbitrary indexes (not necessarily in the diagonal)? (see question edit)

Comment: @goncalopp I guess just any (fancy) indexing on thew `view` array or reshaped `view` array...

Answer (score 1):

Here is your solution:

```
v = np.arange(0,original.shape[0],0.5).astype(int)
result = np.c_[ original[v[1:-1],v[:-2]] , original[v[1:-1],v[2:]] ]
```

works for any size of the square input matrix ("original" as you called it).

The idea is to create a "helper array" v, which is simply [0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,...], and then use the observation that the indices you need are always simple slices of v.

Enjoy!

Comment: I'm still trying to understand that zigzagging on the second line... is there a way to do this on arbitrary slice sizes (not necessarily 2x2)? and for arbitrary slice positions, not necessarily along the diagonal.

Comment: @goncalopp arbitrary square slice size should be a straightforward extension. Arbitrary positions might be trickier - the bottom line is that you can use indexing to get slices, you just need to list the right order. In any case, your question was very specific and it wasn't clear which variables you want to generalize, so if you want something specific please put it in the question.

Comment: If I understood your method correctly, extracting n*n sized slices would require n arguments for np.c_? I edited the question for clarification