# Equivalent Python for the following R index-averaging code

Tags: python, r

The commands below are for finding the average of specific x, y, z-indices within an array.  In the larger problem I'm attempting to solve, a 2Gb file is read into a 4D array, where the first 3 dimensions are related to space (x, y, z), and the 4th dimension is time.  Since working out this R script, I've since gone to python for reading in the 2Gb file containing the data and would like to convert the lines of R script below to Python, so I can do it all in one language.  Does anyone know the equivalent Python for this?:

```
# create a small example dataset for testing out script
test_dat <- array(rnorm(10*10*4*50), dim=c(10,10,4,50))  

# create a list of specific indices I want the average of (arbitrary
# in this case, but not in the larger problem at hand)
xyz_index <- list(c(2,10,1), c(4,5,1), c(6,7,1), c(9,3,1)) 

# bind the index data into a matrix for the next step
m <- do.call(rbind,xyz_index) ## 4x3 matrix 

# will return the average of the values in test_dat that are 
# in the positions listed in xyz_index for each time index 
# (50 values in this small problem)
sapply(seq(dim(test_dat)[4]), function(i) mean(test_dat[cbind(m,i)]))
```

Comment: If the only reason to migrate from R is the memory issues, then solve them, already - you can do this iteratively - don't need to keep the entire image in-memory. Or if you want to do it in Python, use NumPy arrays and/or PIL. You're trying to solve a non-problem.

Comment: smci, I'm not keeping the entire image in-memory, that's the beauty of the employed python script that processes the 2Gb-worth of 4d-array info. So that I can remain in one environment, I'm still wondering what the equivalent python is for the following bit of R?: 'sapply(seq(dim(test_dat)[4]), function(i) mean(test_dat[cbind(m,i)]))'

Comment: **You don't need to keep it in-memory in R either.**

Comment: Whether you do this in R or Python numpy, a generic more memory-efficient approach is that you're masking selected x,y,z-elements of a 3D array, then applying an average filter, and sweeping that through the t-axis (t=1..50)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want, please confirm.
Turns out concatenating multiple slices is very painful in numpy and apparently in [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) too. You really don't want to write obscure code like [these stride tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12878288/numpy-assembling-multiple-slices-into-new-array).

```
import numpy as np

test_dat = np.random.randn(10,10,4,50)

#xyz_index <- list(c(2,10,1), c(4,5,1), c(6,7,1), c(9,3,1))     
#m <- do.call(rbind,xyz_index) ## 4x3 matrix 
# I'm not sure about this, but it seems to get the 4x50 submatrix of concatenated slices
# see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21349133/numpy-array-integer-indexing-in-more-than-one-dimension
m = np.r_[ '0,2', test_dat[2,9,1,:], test_dat[4,5,1,:], test_dat[6,7,1,:], test_dat[9,3,1,:] ]

# Compute .mean() of values, sweep over t-axis
#sapply(seq(dim(test_dat)[4]), function(i) mean(test_dat[cbind(m,i)]))
m.mean(axis=1)
```

By the way, I also looked at [numpy masked array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.ma.html)